# Getting sound directly from hardware with C#

Tags: c#, audio

Is there a way to get the sound that the sound card is playing directly from the hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAudio is a nice API for sound programming in C#. I'm only discovered it myself, but it might be able to record the output, though probably not...

http://www.codeplex.com/naudio

Comment: Just tried out a NAudio sample code and i can confirm it does record speaker output. well, with my crappy inbuilt sound card anyway

Answer (score 0):

some sound cars can select the output sound as mic, if that is acceptable then you could just google how to use the microphone...

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is Windows since you are using C#.  Ignore this if you are using mono.

There is no officially supported way to do this in Windows.  Some sound cards have a setting in the mixer that will set the wave record input to 'what you hear'.  So on those cards, you could just set that setting and then record audio.

edit:

I should add that if your driver doesn't have built in support for recording what it's outputing, then you will need to write or purchase a driver that does.  I've heard that TotalRecorder can do this.

Comment: That's an option but i don't want having the user to manually change settings the program should handle everything.

Comment: It's possible to programatically manipulate the mixer, although you may have to write unmanaged code to do it.  And the mixer api is a pain to work with.

Comment: And what if my program is playing the sound itself ?

Comment: Then save the data before you play it, of course.  That would be much easier.

Comment: The thing i want to do is play a youtube clip inside my program and the sound capture the sound of the movie. It should also work with sounds from other sources, but youtube is what i want to start with.

Comment: Total Recorder is the easiest general purpose way I know of to do this.  This is a hard problem unless you write drivers for a living.

Comment: If you're really only trying to strip the sound from a YouTube video, you have a completely different (almost certainly easier) problem than trying to record from the sound card.

Answer (score 0):

The most general way is [Total Recorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/) which has a COM interface.